# How to hide and show navigation button of toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a toolbar inside a `collapsingtoolbar` layout. I would like to show the navigation icon only when the `collapsingtoolbar` is expanded and hide it when it is collapsed. Is there anyway to do this aside from `setNavigationIcon(null)` and `setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow)`? As those two methods seem to not work

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true/false);` and `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true/false);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this piece of line when you want the  navigation button to be displayed getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

And use this piece of line when you want to hide
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);